# Meaning of "range quantity production"

Tags: meaning

Please help me figure out the meaning of "range quantity production" in the following sentence:

"But it was not until the invention of the water frame by Richard
Arkwright, a barber, in 1769, that range quantity production of both warp
and woof (latitudinal fibres) became possible."

You will find more reference [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Pcf1nrvUwD0C&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=%22range%20quantity%20production%22&source=bl&ots=IPeL3stbrU&sig=dYdR2Uip9IfM9ysaBi6rsYENuQI&hl=hi&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMk9iRzcfWAhWIO48KHWTPCEgQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22range%20quantity%20production%22&f=false).

Comment: I imagine production in quantities that would only be possible in a large farm/ranch operation, as opposed to a smaller producer. You should tell us the meaning of "range" in this context, just to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand "range quantity production" as a process of producing some product in bundles/bunches - i.e. kind of machine creates 5 things (toys, tools, etc) in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Production range is the ability of an organisation to produce multifunctional product as per the requirements or according to the customer need

Comment: But that's not what's being asked about.